# files have no ownership permissions and can't assign ownership

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

I'm having problems with file permissions on a server 2008 R1 server.

Office 2010 tmp files are being created, and don't have any security permissions assigned. They aren't being deleted, I can't assign ownership, and I can't delete them.

I downloaded and ran the sysinternals tool handle.exe. When running it for the first time, handle64.exe was created, but not assigned any permissions. I cannot assign ownership and cannot delete it.

Seemingly random files in random places don't seem to have any permissions assigned. Access is denied when attempting to change ownership to administrator or the administrators group.

If I try to replace inheritable permissions of the folder these files are in, access is denied for the files with no permissions.

I attempted to use subinacl to view the ownership information on the files that had no permissions, but access was denied here as well.

I also tried setting the owner with [setacl](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/) in an elevated cmd window, but access was denied as well.

This problem only surfaced in the last few days, and I'm unsure as what the cause is or how to correct it.

Comment: see anything in the logs that looks out of the ordinary?

Comment: It looks like the server crashed and restarted itself the day before the issue started happening. After rebooting it today, the issue seems to have resolved itself.

Comment: hmm did you see anything in the logs right after the last crash, suspect a slightly corrupted file system..

Comment: Nope, nothing to indicate anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rebooting the server. Whatever the problem was, it cleared itself up, and permissions for the files without permissions had their permissions listed. Very strange.